# Can you turn two inductively coupled conductors into a transformer?

Tags: transformer, wireless, electromagnetism, conductors

So I'm working on a school project, and to be honest. Don't know a lot about electromagnetism. I want to make a wireless charging station that could be plugged into the outlet. Of course I don't want to actually use 230V (I live in Europe), so I'd like to turn that into 12V. And for that you need a transformer. But I was wondering whether you can, instead of using a transformer, have the coils serve two jobs. And have them transform, and wirelessly transmit and receive energy at the same time. And if that is possible, would that work the same way as a transformer. By turning one coil a few more times?

Comment: Depending on what exactly you mean by "wireless" you might want to replicate what most electrical toothbrushes do: split the transformer  across device and charging station.

Comment: You would be better off if you first rectified the mains voltage and then drove a coil in the kHz to MHz range. Otherwise you're going to need insanely much copper and iron for the 50 Hz frequency. - And there are so many things that can go wrong, and when you are a beginner, working with mains, then it's usually better to just buy something that already works. Or risk dying, your choice.

Comment: The way electrical toothbrushes charges won't really work for my project. Because you have to get a part of the transformer's core inside the receiving end. And I won't be able to do that.

But yeah, reading Harry Svensson's comment made me realize I had totally forgotten about the safety aspect of plugging a self made transformer into mains. I think it'll just be the smartest to just get something that already works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you're correct, a (mains) transformer and wireless charging do work based on the same principles.

However there are some differences in the practical implementations that makes combining the two, as you suggest, difficult to impossible.

Mains voltage uses 50 or 60 Hz AC, so quite a low frequency. That means a transformer for a certain amount of power needs to be big an heavy. Notice how some old power adapters are quite big and heavy, these have a 50 / 60 Hz transformer inside.

Modern power adapters like the one you use to charge your phone also has a transformer **but** one that works at a **much higher** frequency. In the order of 100 kHz. That means that the transformer can be much smaller and lighter for the same amount of power compared to a 50 / 60 Hz transformer. The difference in size and weight can easily be a factor 10. Also the newer types are much cheaper to make.

Wireless charging usually also works at a frequency of around 100 kHz so indeed you could theoretically combine the two, meaning the high frequency transformer is replaced by two wireless charging transmit coils. But then you still need a circuit to convert 50 / 60 Hz  into 100 kHz.

Such circuits exist, actually that is what is inside nearly all modern mains adapters. However these circuits operate on the rectified AC mains voltage. That's close to 400 V DC and **very dangerous** especially for those without proper experience.

So while what you propose is theoretically true, it isn't something that you (as a beginner) can design or work with. It is simply too dangerous.

Your best bet is to get buy a ready made wireless charging module which are powered over USB. There are also small wireless charging receiver modules that can be attached to a phone. These are only a couple of $ each and your best bet at getting wireless power transfer to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, that's how the wireless chargers do it. Consider a Flyback transformer (https://training.ti.com/understanding-basics-flyback-converter) only instead of you having the Flyback in one package you'll have you primary side connected to the mains and the secondary side will be a physically different winding with a case or a housing providing the isolation, with the added effect of being able to remove the secondary physically away from the primary winding.

Comment: I would consider that transformer if it was shown as a schematic, or image, not a video.

Comment: I'd say, **yes but no** to this answer as mains is at 50 or 60 Hz and flyback transformers and wireless charging usually works at at least 100 kHz. So yes for "theoretically true" but no due to "the frequencies being so much different that it will not work like that"

Comment: @HarrySvensson The video is a nice to know jumping off point, Marble said he didn't know much about EM and Texas Instruments have a lot of materiel on the subject.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie this is true and he can make a SMPS for this I doubt (and hope) Marble don't plan to have the charger directly tied to mains. I also only said consider a flyback not told Marble to use one again it's only a jumping off point.